# There is a way to remove http to https redirection on azure webapp?

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-webapps

The question is very simple. I want to allow http on my azure webapp, but by default it redirects http to https even if "https only" is off. There is a way to keep http protocol at azure webaps? All the information I find on google is the opposite of what I want.

Comment: Just check if there's a HTTP to HTTPS redirection rule configured in your web.config.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I haven't any redirect configuration on my web config.

Comment: Have you tried ctrl+f5 with the url or an anonymous tab? My guess is that if it has a certificate on azure it will redirect to https

Comment: Caio, I dont have a certificate, that's the point. I want to redirect and stay in http for avoid "invalid certificate" issue on HTTPS requests

Comment: Got it. You can do that applying a redirect rule on web.config, I'll sketch an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options here, the one I prefer is applying a certificate to your app. That's free using azure app service. You can learn more on this [arcticle](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/secure-your-custom-domains-at-no-cost-with-app-service-managed-certificates-preview/):

The second one is applying a [redirect rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) within you web.config, redirecting any https to http.

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTP" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```